# Conditional blocks in XAML

Tags: wpf, xaml, controls, conditional-statements

I would like to write a conditional control as below:

```
<local:ConditionalBlock Condition={Binding CertainBoolValue}>
    <ConditionalBlock.Match>
        <!-- Any content here -->
    </ConditionalBlock.Match>
    <ConditionalBlock.Else>
        <!-- Any content here -->
    </ConditionalBlock.Else>
</local:ConditionalBlock>
```

At the moment I don't know how this should be implemented. So please help. Thanks

## **EDITING**

While waiting for the response I have implemented my own solution using Custom Control & control template as following:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Sample
{
    public class ConditionalControl : ContentControl
    {
        static ConditionalControl()
        {
            DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(ConditionalControl), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(ConditionalControl)));
        }

        public object Alternative
        {
            get { return (object)GetValue(AlternativeProperty); }
            set { SetValue(AlternativeProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty AlternativeProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Alternative", typeof(object), typeof(ConditionalControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

        public bool Condition {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ConditionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ConditionProperty, value); }
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty ConditionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Condition", typeof(bool), typeof(ConditionalControl), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
    }
}
```

ConditionalControl.xaml

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Sample">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:ConditionalControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:ConditionalControl}">
                    <Grid>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="match"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Name="alternative" ContentSource="Alternative" />
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="Condition" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="match" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="alternative" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="Condition" Value="False">
                            <Setter TargetName="match" Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                            <Setter TargetName="alternative" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Sample usage:

```
<Grid>
    <local:ConditionalControl Condition="{Binding CertainBoolValue}">
        <Label>Match case</Label>
        <local:ConditionalControl.Alternative>
            <Label>Alternative case</Label>
        </local:ConditionalControl.Alternative>
    </local:ConditionalControl>
</Grid>
```

Anyway, thank Luke Woodward for your prompt response. I'll mark your answer as accepted

Comment: Have you looked at DataTriggers? You could put a DataTrigger in your style that uses different ControlTemplates based on the Condition

Comment: You can get /similar/ functionality using a converter as described here: http://blog.greatrexpectations.com/2012/10/04/getting-rid-of-xaml-boilerplate/

Comment: @pickles: thanks, I have used ControlTemplate.Triggers in my solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to create a UserControl with the following XAML:

```
<ContentControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.ConditionalBlock"
                xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" />
```

and the following code-behind:

```c#
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
    public partial class ConditionalBlock : ContentControl
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty ConditionProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Condition", typeof(bool), typeof(ConditionalBlock),
                                        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(Condition_Changed));

        public ConditionalBlock()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Loaded += ((s, e) => UpdateContent());
        }

        public bool Condition
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(ConditionProperty); }
            set { SetValue(ConditionProperty, value); }
        }

        public object Match { get; set; }

        public object Else { get; set; }

        private static void Condition_Changed(DependencyObject obj, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var conditionalBlock = obj as ConditionalBlock;
            if (conditionalBlock != null)
            {
                conditionalBlock.UpdateContent();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateContent()
        {
            Content = (Condition) ? Match : Else;
        }
    }
}
```

Note that we've changed the superclass from `UserControl` to `ContentControl`.

This uses a dependency property for the condition, so that we get notified when the bound value changes.  When the condition changes, we update which content is visible by assigning to the `Content` dependency property we inherit from `ContentControl`.  Finally, to ensure that one or other content appears when the control is first shown, we update the content in a handler for the `Loaded` event.  (Calling it from within the constructor doesn't work, as at that point the `Match` and `Else` properties haven't been set.)

I've assumed that the content of the `Match` and `Else` properties won't change, so I haven't bothered to implement them as dependency properties.